# Describe a subring of the ring of functions from a monoid to a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $H$ be a non-empty set and $S$ the set of all finite sequences over $H$, including the empty sequence $e := ()$. We make $S$ a monoid by deﬁning a multiplication on $S$ by concatenation. Let $R$ be a ring with $1$, and $R[S]$ be the set of all functions from $S$ to $R$. For $f, g ∈ R[S]$ and $x ∈ S$, deﬁne $(f + g)(x) := f (x) + g(x)$, and $$(f g)(x):=\sum_{(a,b)\ \in \ S\times S\ : \ ab \ =\ x} f(a)g(b),$$ which makes $R[S]$ a ring. For $h ∈ H$ , deﬁne $f_h ∈ R[S]$
by $f_h((h)) := 1$ and $f_h(s) := 0$ for $s\neq (h)$. The question is: What is the subring of $R[S]$ generated by $\{f_h, h ∈ H\}$ and the identity element of $R[S]$?

I could be wrong, but I believe that the identity $I$ of $R[S]$ is the function such that $I(s)=1$ if $s=e:=()$ and $I(s)=0$ otherwise. But I don't understand why the subring of the question is in fact a subring. For example, suppose $H=\{u,v\}$. Then, $(f_u+f_v)((u))=(f_u+f_v)((v))=1$, and I guess that $f_u+f_v$ could be $1$ only for one $h\in H$.

I'd appreciate if someone could help. Sorry about the long text, it is my first time here, and I'm not that good in English. Thank you!

Comment: The subring generated by a subset is by definition a subring: there is nothing else to understand about its subring-ness.

Comment: You are essentially identifying $H$ as a subset of $R[S]$: the subring generated by the $f_h$'s should be the entire ring!

Comment: @rschwieb, Thanks for your help, I understood the first comment. But it isn't clear for me why the subring generated by the $f_h$'s should be the entire ring. For exemple, if $H=\{u,v\}$, how to generate the function $f_x$ that takes $(uv)$ to $1$ and any other $(s)$ to $0$ from $f_u$ and $f_v$? Moreover, the images of the functions in the subring generated by the $f_h$'s is $\{0,1\}$. What about the other elements of $R$?

Comment: Oops, you're right in the last line: instead, you should get $\mathbb Z_n[S]$ where $\mathbb Z_n$ is the subring of $R$ generated by $1$

Comment: "how to generate the function that takes uv to 1?" Just look at the definition of $f_uf_v$

Comment: I should probably stop flooding the comments with a solution, so I've started writing them in the solution area. By the way, your post's size and contents are very appropriate. There are some people who don't explain anything about what they are stuck with, and it's sometimes impossible to deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe that the identity $I$ of $R[S]$ is the function such that $I(s)=1$ if $s=e:=()$ and $I(s)=0$ otherwise.

Yes, that's right. It might be helpful to go one step further and note that we can identify $R$ inside $R[S]$ by the function $r(x)=r$ if $x=e$ and $r(x)=0$ otherwise.

> But I didn't understand why the subring of the question is in fact a subring.

It's OK: the subring generated by a subset $X$ of a ring is *by definition* a subring. If you really want to know what it looks like, it looks like finite sums of finite products of elements of $X$ (including the empty product, which is the identity element.)

> Then, $(f_u+f_v)((u))=(f_u+f_v)((v))=1$ ...

This is correct, and $(f_u+f_v)(x)=0$ for any $x\in S\setminus \{u,v\}$. If $u\neq v$ then indeed $f_u+f_v$ is nonzero on two elements.

> and I guess that $f_u+f_v$ could be $1$ only for one $h\in H$.

No... there isn't any reason to expect that. In general $f_x$ is going to be nonzero on finitely many elements of $S$. If you can pick $10^6$ distinct elements of $S$ and add them this way, the resulting function is $1$ on those $10^6$ places.

### An observation

What is unusual here is that you've defined $R[S]$ to be the *entire set* of functions from $S$ into $R$. $R[S]$ is often used to denote the semigroup ring, but for semigroup rings you need to restrict attention to the functions *which are finitely nonzero*. In fact, I believe you need to add this restriction into what you've written, because otherwise you have no guarantee the sum you're using is defined (what if it's an infinite sum?)

This would bring you into the normal definition of a semigroup ring. Then you can alternatively view the functions as "formal linear combinations" using $S$ as a basis. The function simply tells you what the coefficients of the linear combination are, and because the function has finite support, it is only a finite linear combination.

### The subring

Work to show that it is the group ring $\mathbb Z_n[S]$ where $\mathbb Z_n$ is the subring of $R$ generated by $1$. In terms of the definition you've given, it would be the functions $S\to \mathbb Z_n$ of finite support. It's a simple matter to show that these elements form a subring generated by the particular elements you picked out.

Comment: About your observation, I really forgot to say that the monoid multiplication in $S$ is of ﬁnite type, i.e., for each $x\in S$, the set $\{(y, z) : y, z\in S, yz = x\}$ is ﬁnite. Excuse me for that. I appreciate all your explanations and I thank you for be so  regardful! Now I guess I got it!

Comment: @RamonMelo No problem! Glad to help